# How to clear the backbone localstorage

Tags: backbone.js, local-storage

The javascript one seems pretty simple, just localStorage.clear().

Is there anything similar to that for the backbone localstorage, and if not, can someone point me in the right direction on how to do it.

I was thinking about doing something like this:

localStorage.each(localStorage.delete(this))

except this wouldn't point to that element would it?

Comment: Backbone.js doesn't use localStorage out of the box. Are you using [this](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage) or something else?

Comment: There is only one `localStorage` and backbone will leverage that. Do you actually mean how to clear a backbone collection?

Comment: Yes that is what I'm using nrabinowitz, and I guess that is what I mean abraham.

Comment: So I tried using the Collection.reset() method on my collection that is attached to the localstorage, but the elements did not get removed.

Comment: So are you trying to delete everything stored in localStorage, or just a collection on the client and that collection in localStorage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Few ways you can do this from the Collection, but whichever way you choose, you have to call destroy on each model, which will run sync and destroy it on both the client-side and server-side (which localStorage is acting as).

```
collection.each(function(model) {
      model.destroy();
    }
)
```

---

**Update**

Per comments, doesn't look like this works anymore. Since this is still marked as the answer, including answer that should work below, per `skcin7`.

```
while ((model=collection.shift())) 
    { model.destroy();
}
```

Comment: thank you dc- the destroy function is the one I was looking for.

Comment: what if i only want to delete the first data added?

Comment: @Dreyfus15 then just call .destroy() on that specific element. For instance: collections.get(id).destroy();

Comment: I found that this wasn't working... it would remove only some records, not all. Something with modifing collection while iterating over it i guess. I ended up with this: 
    var length = collection.length;
    for (var i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        collection.at(i).destroy();
    }

Comment: This solution provided will not work, due to a complication with the model positions in the `collection` array being munged as they are deleted. A better solution is: `while ((model=collection.shift()) ) { model.destroy(); }`. Credit to user `fbynite` for this solution which I am using now.

Answer (score 5):

I know this kind of feels like grave digging, but i've been looking for a solution to this for a while now and none of the above snippets seemed to work for me. I always ended up having the size of the collection decreased by half, no matter how i tried it.

So after a decent amount of fiddling, i came up with this:

```
var length = collection.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    collection.at(0).destroy();
}
```

Backbone is removing items "on the fly", so if you have 40 items you won't be able to delete the 21. item because there are only 20 items left. Strangely enough this also seems to affect the collection.each() function which really seems like a bug to me..

Comment: I explained why this happens [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18395310/722238), along with a solution.

Comment: How do you clear the localStorage if you are not using a collection but a single model, I just want to clear the localstorage of the data created... it is creating a key called music : value some numberletter combo and then another key of music with the value from before and its new value the correct array of info I have... see this question for the code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472777/clear-localstorage-and-change-the-view-backbone

Answer (score 1):

Just iterating over the collection and calling destroy on each element is not save in any case.
The reason is iterating over collection modified at the same time can produce unexpected results.

It is better to first clone the collection and iterate over this clone. Checkout [this.each not iterating through collection correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407736/this-each-not-iterating-through-collection-correctly) for further details.

Example:

```
_.chain(Todos.models).clone().each(function(model){
  console.log('deleting model ' + model.id);
  model.destroy();
});
```

Comment: Instead of `_.chain(Todos.models)` you could also do `Todos.chain().clone()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do this programmatically, you can always open up Developer Mode (F12), navigate to the Resources tab, select "Local Storage" from the left pane and delete the records.

**Update:** In the newer versions of Chrome, the Resources tab has been replaced with the Application tab.

Answer (score 0):

```
// dc was so close!
let model;
while ( model = collection.at(0) ) {
    model.destroy();  // removes model from server and collection
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.