# Clear localStorage and change the view Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, local-storage

Hey so I am using backbone localstorage and every time someone hits the search button I want to clear the localstorage so I can just add the new data to the localStorage.

Also, trying to figure out how to then redirect the user to a new view after the success callback in for the localstorage being set, I know there is view.remove() but I am not sure how to use that being that the callback is within the view and also, where/how to render the new view...

Let's say the new view is PageView...

Here is the code for the current search view:

```
    define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/search',
  'text!templates/search.html',

], function($, _, Backbone, SearchM, SearchT){ 

  var Search = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: SearchM,
    el: $("#Sirius"),

    events: {
      'submit #searchMusic': 'search'
    },
    search: function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      //create new instance of the model
      searchM = new SearchM();

      //post instance to the server with the following input fields
      searchM.save({
        channel: this.$('#channel').val(),
        week: this.$('#week').val(),
        year: this.$('#year').val(),
        filter: this.$('#filter').val()
      },{success: storeMusic});

      // on success store music on client-side localStorage
      function storeMusic (model, response, options) {
        console.log('store');
        //create new instance of the localStorage with the key name
        searchM.localStorage = new Backbone.LocalStorage("music");
        clearLocalStorage();
        saveToLocalStorage(response);
      };
      function clearLocalStorage () {
        console.log('clear');
          //removes the items of the localStorage
          this.localStorage.clear();

          //pops out the first key in the records
          searchM.localStorage.records.shift();

        };
        function saveToLocalStorage (response) {
          console.log('save');
          searchM.save({music: response}, {success: nextPage});
        };
         function nextPage () {
          console.log('entered next page');
          searchM.set('display', true);
        };


    },
    render: function () { 

    }
  });
    return Search;
});
```

Container view:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'views/search',
  'text!templates/search.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, SearchV, SearchT){ 

  var Container = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#Sirius"),
    render: function () { 
      var search = new SearchV();
      this.$el.html( SearchT );
      this.listenTo(searchM, 'change:display', console.log('changed MODEL'));
    }

      });
    return Container;
});
```

Here is the model:

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone) {

  var Search = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/music',
    defaults: {
        display: false
    }

  });
  return Search;
});
```

----------------EDIT Confused with below

This is the container and SearchM(model), SearchV(view), SearchT(template)...

```
var Container = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#Sirius"),
    render: function () { 
      //Model CREATED
      searchM = new SearchM();

     //VIEW Created
      var search = new SearchV();
      this.$el.html( SearchT );
    }
      });
    return Container;
});
```

This is the search View - so I took out the model from here, but calling this or this.model actually does not work, as searchM is not defined and the model does not seemed to be passed in... I only added the two methods so ignore the rest for now, if I can make these work then everything can follow suit

```
var Search = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $("#Sirius"),

    events: {
      'submit #searchMusic': 'search'
    },
    search: function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();



      //post instance to the server with the following input fields
      searchM.save({
        channel: this.$('#channel').val(),
        week: this.$('#week').val(),
        year: this.$('#year').val(),
        filter: this.$('#filter').val()
      },{success: storeMusic()});

     function nextPage () {
          console.log('entered next page');
          searchM.set('display', true);
          this.listenTo(searchM, 'change:display', console.log('changed MODEL'));
          console.log(searchM.display);
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get rid of the model:

```
searchM.destroy();
```

That's basically the same as in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911588/how-to-clear-the-backbone-localstorage/18967875#18967875), but for a single model.

As for the view changing, i would recommend adding a 'display' or 'loaded' variable to the model, which is false by default and set to true, when the data is ready. Then, have the view listen to the 'change:display' event, triggering the render() method when ready. You can delete the old view, as soon as you know the data has changed and replace it with some loading spinner, which then will be replaced by the new data view.
Hope this helped.

Confused parts:

```
var Container = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#Sirius"),
    render: function () { 
      //Model CREATED
      searchM = new SearchM();

     //VIEW Created
      var search = new SearchV({model: searchM});
      this.$el.html( SearchT );
    }
});

var Search = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $("#Sirius"),

    events: {
      'submit #searchMusic': 'search'
    },
    initialize: function () {
         this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:display', this.displayChanged);
    },
    displayChanged: function () {
       console.log('display changed');
    },
    search: function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      //post instance to the server with the following input fields
      searchM.save({
         channel: this.$('#channel').val(),
         week: this.$('#week').val(),
         year: this.$('#year').val(),
         filter: this.$('#filter').val()
      },{success: storeMusic()});
    },
    nextPage: function () {
        console.log('entered next page');
        searchM.set('display', true);
        console.log(searchM.display);
    },
```

Comment: Where would I call searchM.destroy() ... because I am creating a new instance of it for each time something is being stored in the localStorage... also, for some reason my code puts in the parameters ?channel=2&week=1&year=2011&filter= a query string like that, which I want to get rid of since it affects the search button for some reason...

Comment: You could call it right at the beginning of the listStore() method.

Comment: Where does it put the params? Because it really should't matter, since the button should not actually fire it's event, you have to listen for it in JS and prevent the Default. (event.preventDefault()).

Comment: awesome that worked out... the searchM.destroy did not work out but look at what I did instead and tell me if that will cause problems, I am editing the code, basically I am clearing the storage and then shifting out the first /random generated key... which actually works for clearing the storage tho

Comment: Can you give an example of the view change variable that you are mentioning? And should I use a container view or what is the best practice for changing views, while keeping the same route

Comment: i'd say you have to remove the model first, then create the new one, so put clearLocalStorage(); to the top. also, creating functions inside a function is rarely a good idea ;)

Comment: and while doing that, try it again with .destroy()

Comment: generally i recommend you split all your backbone pieces into one seperate file. you have done this with you search view and the container, so go ahead and create a file for your model. the backbone model has [default properties](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults), add 'display' as a default value (false). in your load success handler, you then simply add searchM.set('display', true); and in the initialize method of the search view you add this.listenTo(searchM, 'change:display', this.render); this will trigger render, if the display value changes, which it does on load. hope that helped.

Comment: additionally, since you are just changing data, you can leave the model in place and just change the display value to false and update its data. since there will be another model created, there really is no need to destroy and recreate the model

Comment: Does it matter if I do model.destroy() vs what I currently have done? Also, I have meant to take out all the functions... is that ok the way I did it? Also, I added the display to model and added the code here for my model... and now the dilemma is how do I tell the container view that the model has changed display, as you can see it happens in the next page function...  Also, is there a way to send back a callback to the view being rendered in the container view somehow?

Comment: I added the listenTo to the container as that is where searchV is initiated... but it says searchM is not defined... which is the case since it is being created in the searchView which the container only says render it and thats it..

Comment: looks good so far. in the model, `default` should be `default**s**`. i just noticed that pretty much everything is defined inside the search method. reusing code in functions is great, but re-defining these functions every time `.search()` is called is bad. add these functions to your search view. you can then call the methods like this: `this.storeMusic()`.

Comment: just create the model right before you initialize. there is no harm in it being there from the beginning and it will have the default values already set.

Comment: i meant at the top of initialize(), which you should add to the container view. and you have to make the search view listen to the searchModel change, not the container view. the way backbone works is it dipatches these change events so the view can react instantly if something changed. a great way to see this in action is [TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com/). it's a todo app implemented in all major mv* frameworks including backbone. you can browse the code in github and it's well documented. i've used a lot of it when i started out.

Comment: what is default**s** I am confused how to display that... is it default**s**: { display: false}  Also, when you say move the functions should they be like so storeMusic: function () {} just like the way the search function is? How does the container view then pickup that a change has occured, because even after I set it in the nextPage function and then console.log (searchM.display) it shows up as undefined

Comment: ``**``is how you make bold text here, so it should have been defaults. and yes, you define your new methods just like the search method. so ``this.search();`` would also work in that scope.

Comment: you can listen for changes with the ``.listenTo()`` method. you may have to copy the line to where your model is recreated, because events will likely be destroyed if the model is destroyed. you can avoid this by letting the model stick around and just change it's data. that's the best way to go.

Comment: Sorry I am not visualizing it, can you edit your answer with my structure on just the part to change for the listenTo... I will add an edit on my answer with the parts I am confused about... if you can just visually show me what you are referring to

Comment: it's all in the todoMVC project. look at [this](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/architecture-examples/backbone/js/views/todo-view.js) file, copy the initialize method to your search view and edit it like you had before (listening to change:display)

Comment: as for your confused part above: 1. you can omit ``this.`` when getting the form data. 2. ``this`` is always dependent on the scope you are in. so calling ``this`` in your function will not work. if you add nextPage() as a method of your search view (as said before), it will be part of the search view (.. fixing ``this``).

Comment: thank you for all your help and sticking it out with me hehe, I am going to look at the todomvc and try to use his understanding to learn from it

Comment: no problem man, i edited my answer above with a bit of code of you confused parts. hang in there ;)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Backbone.LocalStorage before, and the documentation doesn't specify how you should clear the data, however, in the [source code](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage/blob/master/backbone.localStorage.js) there is a `_clear()` method that should do the trick:

```
function listStore (model, response, options) {
        searchM.localStorage = new Backbone.LocalStorage("music");
        searchM.localStorage._clear();
        searchM.save({music: response}, {success: console.log('success')
});
```

As for switching to a new View, that is generally handled using a [Backbone.Router](http://backbonejs.org/#Router) which will handle redirecting your users to any area of your application you wish.

```
var MyRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

  routes: {
    "search/:query":        "search",  // #search/kiwis
    "page":                 "page"   // #page
  },

  page: function() {
    new PageView(); //etc...
  },

  search: function(query) {
    ...
  }

});

//this line is required to tell Backbone that your routes are ready
Backbone.history.start();
```

Once you have the appropriate routes established, you can navigate to the desired location by calling:

```
function listStore (model, response, options) {
            //check to see if the LS exists, and clear it if so
            if(searchM.localStorage){
               searchM.localStorage._clear();
            }
            searchM.localStorage = new Backbone.LocalStorage("music");
            searchM.save({music: response}, {success: console.log('success');
            searchM.on('sync', function(){
               MyRouter.navigate("page", {trigger: true});
            });
    });
```

Comment: I actually was thinking of doing a container view (since I want to keep  it all on one page) but if I make a container view or even use the router to remove and make a new view how do I say once the success callback is hit after storing to the localStorage, for the container/router to know to remove the view and add the new one... Also, searchM.localStorage is undefined... I think it will always be undefined so I have to maybe try to fetch it and see if it exists or something

Comment: The Backbone router allows you to keep your application "on one page" while actually changing the app content. It uses the URL hash (or pushState on newer browsers) to alter the browser location without refreshing the full page.

Comment: As for changing the view, you'll want to listen for the `sync` event broadcast from the searchM model. I'll update the answer to illustrate

Comment: Looking back at your code, I'm a bit confused on the goal. You're calling `searchM.save()`, which when successful, calls `listStore()`, which executes another `save()` on the same model, but with different options?  Is the first `save()` meant to be a `fetch()`?  In any event, I've transposed the `new BB.LocalStorage` and `clear()` calls to fix the undefined problem

Comment: Sorry, yes the first save is posting the user input to the server and taking back the response, and then I am saving that info to the localStorage after creating the localStorage.

Comment: Also, how are you making the call to MyRouter?